# dynamic_sidebar(1)… how to add some post data in this dynamic_sidebar

Tags: wordpress

Hello i am very new to wordpress and working on a theme. This is a video theme and there is some bookmark links on each video post, when i click any video then the these bookmark appear on these posts.

But on my front page latest video post appearing in sequence by dynamic_sidebar(1). I just want to add these bookmark link on front page showing video, so i have to change some dynamic_sidebar(1) code, but i searched and i dont know where it is...so help me(I know its not a big deal).

and what am I trying to do...I am trying to implement same code on front page with side bar(I know I am stupid) as:

as

```
<div class="bookmark_links">
                          <?php if(function_exists('the_ratings')) { the_ratings(); } ?> 


                   <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'views_count',true)){?>
                        <span class="post-views" >
                        Total Views : <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'views_count',true);?>
                        </span> 
                    <?php }?> 


                   <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'twitter',true)){?>
             <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'twitter',true);?>" target="_blank" class="i_twitter"> <?php _e('Twitter','templatic');?> </a> 
             <?php }?> 

              <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID,'facebook',true)){?>
                   <a href=" <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'facebook',true);?>" target="_blank" class="i_facebook"> <?php _e('Facebook','templatic');?> </a> 
             <?php }?>  

     <div class="share"> 
        <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;username=xa-4c873bb26489d97f" class="addthis_button_compact sharethis"><?php _e('Share Video','templatic');?></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=xa-4c873bb26489d97f"></script>
    </div>
```

Please tell me what should i do... any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figuring out what file is responsible for generating the post on the front page is not necessarily trivial.  It could be index.php or home.php, or something else entirely, depending on your theme.  Here is a link that demonstrates 2 ways to figure out which template is serving the current page:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37292/how-do-you-find-out-which-template-page-is-serving-the-current-page

Keep in mind that the template may be using yet another file to actually go through The Loop.  The bottom line is that you must find The Loop (i.e., main WordPress Query) that generates the post on the front page.  Once you find that, move the code you got from the sidebar to an appropriate place inside The Loop.  I recommend only one change in the code you showed: change

`post->ID`

to

`get_the_ID()`

which works only when inside The Loop.

By the way, if you are quite new to WP, I suggest you get to know and understand The Loop (http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) thoroughly, since that lies at the heart of what WP does.  Good luck!